# AWS AppSync - formatting hardcoded JSON data in response mapping template

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, vtl

I need a GraphQL query returning hardcoded informations as JSON response.

In the AppSync GraphQL schema, I added the following query:

```
type Query {
  getHealthCheck: AWSJSON
}
```

My response mapping template where the values are hardcoded is the following:

```
$util.toJson({"version": "0.1.0"})
```

However, as the response of the query, I get a string instead of a proper JSON, i.e.:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getHealthCheck": "{\"version\":\"0.1.0\"}"
    }
}
```

How can I modify the response mapping template to get a proper JSON? I tried several utils but I'm a bit lost with the data structures in VTL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.

If you think about it, it goes against the idea of even having a GraphQL schema to then return essential arbritrary JSON.

I believe that AWSJSON will parse stringified JSON for inputs, but serialize to stringified JSON for outputs.

There's [an answer to an other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904110/964514) that might give some ideas of how to work around this. Other than that, it seems your client will need to parse the JSON.